# How can I use launchd to periodically run Fake builds?

Tags: macos, launchd, f#-fake

I have a housekeeping Fake build that I'd like to run every hour. My build runs fine from the CLI with `fake run`, but when I try to use it from launchd, it outputs "Error while parsing command line, usage is: etc."

My Housekeeping.plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DOTNET_CLI_HOME</key>
        <string>/Users/larryobrien</string>
    </dict>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>CheckDoing</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/larryobrien/.dotnet/tools/fake</string>
        <string>run</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>CheckDoing.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>CheckDoing.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/larryobrien/src/Housekeeping</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Not sure if this is an SO question or a Superuser question, but since I think it boils down to a familiarity with Fake, I'm going to try it here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with fake, but don't you have to tell it what to run?

Comment: The command `fake run` will automatically run a script called `build.fsx` if that file exists. In this case, I believe that since I have the `WorkingDirectory` key in the .plist, it should pick up that file (which does exist -- `fake run` works fine from the command line).